# ip6tables settings to block the ipv6 fragmentation

Tags: linux, ipv6, rhel

Is it possible to write ip6tables  rules to block ipv6 fragmented packets which are malformed. 
This is basically for the ipv6  certification of our appliance box. We are  running at: rhel 5.5 and kernel : 2.6.18-238.1.1.el5

The tests we are failing currently are:

1) Fragment Reassembly -- Fragment ID mismatch should give error 2) Fragment Reassembly -- Source Addresses Differ Between Fragments 3) Fragment Reassembly -- Destination Address Differ Between Fragments

Any other ideas to solve this is also welcome :)

Comment: This request seems rather odd. One of the major benefits of IPv6 is that routers no longer (in contrast to IPv4) have to care about fragmentation other than signaling that it is necessary. In order to achieve your goals, your router needs to actually do the fragment assembly, so something stateful is needed.

Comment: Agreed. But the IPV6 logo certification suites like TAHI (http://tahi.org) need the error to be sent in 60 secs of receiving the first frame when the subsequent frames are garbled with any one of the above 3 cases. Any idea?

Comment: This is something for the kernel to worry about. Try updating your system; you are several years out of date.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is a appliance built on RHEL 5.5 and hence upgrade is not an option. Is there a kernel change / setting that can solve this?

Comment: SNORT is a viable solution in the case. It can detect and block the issues like IPV6 fragmentation. Steps on using the snort on RHEL 5 linuxmantra.com/2010/10/install-snort-2-9-on-rhel-5.html I am trying that out.... Will update this thread once done.

Comment: just now tested the SNORT based solution and it is working fine. Below are the steps to configure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can solve this via tools like snort. Below are the steps to install, configure and run in RHEL 5.5

## INSTALL PREREQUISITES

For the SNORT we need to install the following:

- flex byacc bison pcre-devel libdnet-devel zlib-devel
- We can download the above from:

ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/dag/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/buildtools/RPMS/flex-2.5.35-0.8.el5.rfb.x86_64.rpm

ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/5.10/os/x86_64/CentOS/byacc-1.9-29.2.2.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/zlib-devel-1.2.3-3.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/bison-2.3-2.1.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/pcre-devel-6.6-2.el5_1.7.x86_64.rpm

ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/dag/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/libdnet-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/libdnet-devel-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

```
* Install the above said rpm in the below order:
rpm -ivh flex-2.5.35-0.8.el5.rfb.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh byacc-1.9-29.2.2.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh zlib-devel-1.2.3-3.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh bison-2.3-2.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh pcre-devel-6.6-2.el5_1.7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libdnet-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libdnet-devel-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

## DOWNLOAD THE REQUIRED SNORT & ALLIED LIBRARIES

http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snort.mirror/files/Snort%202.9.5.6/snort-2.9.5.6.tar.gz/download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snort.mirror/files/Snort%202.9.5.6/daq-2.0.1.tar.gz/download

[ NOTE: The following assumes the above 3 are downloaded to the /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT ]

## INSTALL LIBPCAP

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz

mv libpcap-1.5.3 /usr/local/src/

cd /usr/local/src/libpcap-1.5.3

./configure --prefix=/usr

make

make install

/sbin/ldconfig

## INSTALL DAQ AND SNORT

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf daq-2.0.1.tar.gz

cd daq-2.0.1

./configure

cd os-daq-modules

make

cd ..

make

make install

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf snort-2.9.5.6.tar.gz

cd snort-2.9.5.6

./configure

make

make install

## FIXING THE libdnet LIBRARY ISSUES

cp -rp /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libdnet.so.1 /usr/local/lib/

/sbin/ldconfig

updated

mkdir -p /var/log/snort/

touch /var/log/snort/alert

## TEST THE SNORT

snort --version

,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
  o"  )~   Version 2.9.5.6 GRE (Build 208)
   ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/snort/snort-team
           Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
           Using libpcap version 1.5.3
           Using PCRE version: 6.6 06-Feb-2006
           Using ZLIB version: 1.2.3

## CONFIGURING THE IPV6 FILTER AND RUNNING

vi /opt/test/SNORT/SNORT.conf

preprocessor frag3_global: max_frags 65536

preprocessor frag3_engine: policy linux 
                    bind_to 2001::99ed:d7c6:86f0:8e0a 
                    detect_anomalies

preprocessor frag3_engine: policy linux detect_anomalies

Now run as:

snort -c /opt/test/SNORT/SNORT.conf

NOTE: here the 2001::99ed:d7c6:86f0:8e0a is the eth0 (communication interface) ipv6 address.